# Avoid systemd user scope kill on shutdown

Tags: systemd

I create a Debian Bookworm machine to serve as LXC containers manager.
I use unprivileged LXC containers started with lxc-unpriv-start command that create a systemd user scope. I create a service that start my containers on server start and launch a clean shutdown on service stop. Every container can take 2 or 3 minutes to shutdown. If I stop main service manually all works well.
The problem arise when I shutdown the server because my service correctly wait for containers termination but meanwhile systemd-logind kill all user session brutally killing my container also.

I simulate the situation creating a sleep only shell and execute it with

> /usr/bin/systemd-run --user --scope -p "Delegate=yes" wait.sh &

and it get killed on shutdown.
How can I avoid this kill?

Comment: Can you share the service file? And is the service itself a system service or a user service (i.e. which you manipulate with `systemctl --user`)?

Comment: Hi Tom. There is no service file. lxc-unpriv-start execute a systemd-run command (like the one I showed above) that create a systemd scope, not a service.

Comment: So you always run the command directly from a shell? In that case it means systemd will have no idea about what stop command should be run before it stops the user manager.

Answer (score 0):

Linger should solve that problem.

From https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html

> Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs as argument. If no argument is specified, enables/disables lingering for the user of the session of the caller.

```
loginctl enable-linger <username>
```

Enabling linger for the user session will allow your containers to continue running even after you log out or during system shutdown. This should prevent systemd-logind from forcefully terminating the user session and the associated containers, giving them the opportunity to shut down gracefully.

Comment: Hi Grant. I have already activated linger for user (lxc want it) but shutdown seems to ignore it.
I also added KillUserProcesses=no on logind.conf but nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the container-stopping command "blocks" (i.e., exits after the container has been stopped), you can probably run the container-starting command with a systemd user service instead of directly from a shell. Suppose you need to start multiple containers, you can write a service template to `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/`. The filename of a service template should have `@` before `.service` (e.g. `test@.service`).

Here's an example for you:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=%i.scope
After=%i.scope

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-run --user --scope -u %i sh -c 'sleep 1d &'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sleep 1m
```

As you can see, the scope name needs to be "known" instead of a generated one.

With the template, you can now start the container with e.g. `systemctl --user start test@container-a`. You should now see the corresponding scope remain until its "agent" service has stopped (i.e., the `ExecStop=` command has exited).

You might need to run `systemctl --user daemon-reload` whenever you have made changes in the service (template) file(s).

P.S. Obviously if you need to pass extra container-specific arguments (that are not the same string as the scope name) to the container-starting/stopping command, you probably have to write multiple service files instead of using a template.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm testing right now. I have to personalize "user@.service" to increase TimeoutSec but it works. The only problem remaining is that I can't add a Require directive for lxc system service. In this way when lxc stop gives error because in use.